# Lost all my commit history on github - even reflog isn't helping

Tags: git, github

So I think I just put myself in a dire situation. I had this remote repo that had all my commit history, but recently I couldn't find the cause of the issue in my files so I:

- Downloaded the project from my remote repo into a new folder
- Initialized git, added, committed, but upon pushing, I was getting the following error:

  ```
  hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do  
  hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing 
  hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes 
  hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
  ```
- So I did `git pull` but then got the following:

  ```
  hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind 
  hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 
  hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
  ```
- So I forced push it -> `git push -f origin master` which seemed to have worked.
- Then I did some changed, and now wanted to override my local changed with what's on the remote (now that I have it pushed). I was follwoing the following link for getting it done:
  https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/git-pull-how-to-override-local-files-with-git-pull/13216

So I ran the following commands (probably without fully understanding the consequences):

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

**AND now I don't see my previous commit history at all (only see the one I committed using force push)! Even `reflog` doesn't help. Is there any way to retrieve the lost history at least?**

Comment: @matt `git reflog`

Comment: then how does one find the previous commits? and by where you are, you mean the head?

Comment: I think your problems started because you didn't use `git clone` to create the local working directory

Comment: so you're saying once I changed the remote URL, it lost all the previous stuff?

Comment: pretty much the same except it also mentions `refs/remotes/origin/master@{0}: update by push
46779fc refs/remotes/origin/master@{1}: pull origin master: storing head`. and with the latter command, i get `error: invalid parameter: expected sha1, got '−−lost-found`

Comment: is it supposed to return me something? it just seems to check the objects

Comment: Did you notice if a GC process kicked-in? You're not supposed to have lost all reflog entries.

Comment: after running `git fsck --unreachable`? All I see is `Checking objects: 100% (390/390), done.`

Comment: "*so you're saying once I changed the remote URL, it lost all the previous stuff?*" no, it was `git push --force` that did it. Since you didn't clone the repo, you didn't get the `.git` folder which signifies a repository. So, you just had some files. When you initialised Git, you created a **new repository** as far as Git is concerned. You tried to push but comparing the two repositories, there were multiple commits on the remote, while locally, you only had your new commits. Force pushing told Git to ignore this discrepancy and make the remote *only* have what you have locally.

Comment: But I’m not sure if push should do anything to past commits but rather push whatever local changes are there (atleast that’s what I had in mind). From what you wrote, I guess there’s no way of getting commit history?

Comment: Push would only *add* commits under normal circumstances. However, `git push --force` *overwrites* the entire history to the new one. If you had `A -> B -> C` on the remote but locally you have `A -> B -> D` (you branched at `B`, and didn't get `C` later), then `git push --force` *entirely replaces* what the remote branch has and makes it `A -> B -> D` losing `C`.  In your case you had `A -> B -> C ... -> X` on the remote. You got the files from the repo and created entirely new commit history that consists of `Y -> Z` then force pushed it to the remote branch removing the previous ones.

Comment: It's *possible* that the previous commits are held at the remote but I don't actually know how to check, unfortunately. If they are somehow reachable, then a fix is possible. You'd need to get the *previous commits* then force push them onto the branch overwriting to the previous history state. Then *append* the new commits by cherry-picking or re-creating them from scratch.

Comment: https://objectpartners.com/2014/02/11/recovering-a-commit-from-githubs-reflog/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read from your process you have replaced the history of your remote repo. The process to create a local copy of your remote repo was where you first went wrong.

You should have used `git clone <remote-path>` to create a local working copy instead of downloading just the files which lacks the .git directory. Running  `git init` then created a new repository.

The `git push -f` is what did the damage. Forcing a push is something that you must be very careful about and I would typically advise never do it to a remote repo unless you were the only user of the branch you are pushing to and that your local history is desired.